# execute code depending on the available libraries

Tags: python

suppose I have a function:

```
 def mean(data):
     return sum(data)/len(data)
```

now, if on the system you have numpy it is better to define it as:

```
def man(data):
     return np.mean(data)
```

if you have advanced libraries as [numexpr](http://code.google.com/p/numexpr/) it is better to do:

```
def mean(data):
     return ne.evaluate("sum(data)") / len(data)
```

now... I want to use one of the previous depending on the fact that one library is available or not. What is the better way to do in in python? For example in c/c++ I would have used macros like

```
#ifdef HAS_NUMPY
...
#elseif HAS_NUMEXPRE
...
```

Answer (score 4):

```
try:
   import numpy as np
   HAS_NUMPY = True
except ImportError:
   HAS_NUMPY = False

try:
   import numexpr as ne
   HAS_NUMEXPR = True
except ImportError:
   HAS_NUMEXPR = False


if HAS_NUMPY:
    mean = np.mean
elif HAS_NUMEXPR:
    def mean(data):
        return ne.evaluate("sum(data)") / len(data)
else:
    def mean(data):
        return sum(data)/len(data)
```